# Obsolete code for signing PDF with smartcard

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to sign a PDF file using itextsharp with a smartcard. The only example I could find on how to do that was from http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#signextitextsharp1

However, this example appears to be obsolete, it presents various compilation errors when used with the most recent version of iTextSharp: Methods that no longer exists, use of inappropriate classes etc.

Does anyone have an updated/working version of this code?

Comment: you question title should inform readers that you are looking for an example to sign a pdf with the itext library.

Answer (score 2):

For information on how to sign using the current versions of iText and iTextSharp have a look at [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures), a White Paper by Bruno Lowagie (iText Software).

While the code samples are written in Java, the author is confident that the Java examples are also easy to understand for C# developers who are using iTextSharp instead of iText.

The C#-ified samples can be checked out from [the iTextSharp SVN repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/502/tree/tutorial/signatures/).